# js scroll not working when scrolled on bottom

Tags: javascript, scroll

i just came across this problem with adding a class on scroll. This was the my original script.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
   $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-inverse');
}  else{
   $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-inverse');
}});
```

this didn't work when page was scrolled all the way down and I refreshed site. I solved it by removing "else" and adding aditional "IF". This is the working script.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
   $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-inverse');
} if ($(this).scrollTop() < 100) {
   $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-inverse');
}});
```

Now I don't quite understand the logic behind it. Why is the first script not working properly?

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this for you. You can use offset and then top for the position. Hope this helps :).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).scroll(function(){
 var paragraphPosition = $("#id1").offset();

 var windowPostion = $(window).scrollTop();

 if(paragraphPosition.top < windowPostion + 250){
  $("#id1").addClass("navbar-inverse");
 }
 else if(paragraphPosition.top > windowPostion){
  $("#id1").removeClass("navbar-inverse");
 }
});

});
```

```css
.box{
 height: 200px;
 width: 300px;
 border: 2px solid #000000;
}
.navbar-inverse{
 background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "box">
 Do greatest at in learning steepest. Breakfast extremity suffering one who all otherwise suspected. He at no nothing forbade up moments. Wholly uneasy at missed be of pretty whence. John way sir high than law who week. Surrounded prosperous introduced it if is up dispatched. Improved so strictly produced answered elegance is. 
</div>
<div class = "box">
 Do greatest at in learning steepest. Breakfast extremity suffering one who all otherwise suspected. He at no nothing forbade up moments. Wholly uneasy at missed be of pretty whence. John way sir high than law who week. Surrounded prosperous introduced it if is up dispatched. Improved so strictly produced answered elegance is. 
</div>
<div id = "id1">This is a paragraph</div>
<div class = "box">
 Do greatest at in learning steepest. Breakfast extremity suffering one who all otherwise suspected. He at no nothing forbade up moments. Wholly uneasy at missed be of pretty whence. John way sir high than law who week. Surrounded prosperous introduced it if is up dispatched. Improved so strictly produced answered elegance is. 
</div>
<div class = "box">
 Do greatest at in learning steepest. Breakfast extremity suffering one who all otherwise suspected. He at no nothing forbade up moments. Wholly uneasy at missed be of pretty whence. John way sir high than law who week. Surrounded prosperous introduced it if is up dispatched. Improved so strictly produced answered elegance is. 
</div>
```